# What is the purpose of putting ad/support top?

Tags: league-of-legends

I often see pro league players switch their top and bot - ad/support going top and bruiser going bot. What is the purpose of this switch? Is it more efficient for ganks and securing objectives? Or is it to counter certain team compositions?

Answer (score 4):

The reason they do this is to deny Gold/XP to the enemy's Solo Top and AD Carry, getting an advantage vs certain hard team compositions.

For example: Versus an AD Carry Graves+Alistar/Solo Top Talon. Swapping lanes makes the enemy Solo Top and AD Carry lose allot of CS and XP and maybe confusing them in the process, making them prone to mistakes that normally they wouldn't make.

You can do this with a Cho'gath solo top, I believe. Since he can regenerate his HP easily and farm well even vs 2 opponents due to he's AoE spells.

[Check out this game CLG.NA Vs MiG.Blaze  from the Korean Azubu LoL The Champions Spring 2012 tournament](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9OSWtXMdThc)

Hope this helps :).

Answer (score 4):

Support/AD is used when the opposing AD/Support is stronger/better skilled players than your own Support/AD. As a result, it allows your own AD/support to 2v1 a lane against a top solo which allows you to farm with ease. However, a strong bruiser with sustain has to be used for your own bot lane to survive 1v2 against enemy AD/support.

It's also used for shutting down their top solo at times if their top lane is extremely weak against AD/support 2v1 lane while your top lane is strong for 1v2 at bot lane.

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly used to deny enemy solo top hard.

If you're facing a certain champion on top that you cannot counter or you are afraid of for any reason you can put ad + support top to harass him all day long and deny his cs. However, as you do it, your solo (bot) is also facing ad + support, so you need to have some kind of champion there who can farm safely or sustain a lot of damage. That kind of champion could be yorick or morde (who's acually quite famous for owning 2v1 lanes). I also did it with akali (but that was pre-nerf) by just going invisible under turret and farming very safe. This is a very dangerous tactic and you need to trust your teammates a lot.

Assuming you have a good urgot player on your team you can use an alternative, but similiar tactic. Urgot solo bots, while support goes with your normal solo top champion. Urgot is the type of ad carry that can do 2v1 pretty well, however he wouldn't be utilizing his high early-mid damage, so in that case you need to snowball top very hard and have some kind of hypercarry top or mid (like morde for example).

Answer (score 0):

Lets say my team picks Yorick, Yorick can solo bot pretty easily versus an AD and support, then you put your own AD and support up top to deny their solo top XP and gold, now if they want to swap lanes, so that their solo top goes bot, he loses about 1 minute in doing so, meanwhile my team still gets XP and gold, putting us at an advantage.

When they return to lane my team has more XP thus making laning much easier due to level advantage.

Answer (score 0):

Short and simple anwer: It's viable to switch your top laner with your bot ad and support when your top is something like yorick or chogath, who can handle a 2v1 and not lose much farm, while the enemy is something like Irelia or some other melee hero who needs to put themselves at risk to farm versus 2 players, and will likely get denied a lot of farm and even exp.

Answer (score 0):

Most the time a 2v1 AD/Support vs Top lane is to shut down the enemy top and making your AD's time of farming pretty easy. Plus if the champion forced to solo the enemy bot lane doesn't lose turret and/or fall behind then you should be able to easily come out a turret ahead due to the enemy top not being able to do anything in the 2v1 lane.

The downside is that you lack dragon control, if the enemy team pinks or has an oracle on dragon then you are in constant fear of losing it as the enemy team can have 4 at dragon and you can only have 3.